# Finding names and surname in different order in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to code an SQL query that is able to find the same value "exposed" in different ways.
Now I try explain better.

I have a column containing names and surnames (also if you have more than one), everythig together like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|              TABLE_1               |
--------------------------------------
|                NAME                |
--------------------------------------
|           John Frusciante          |
--------------------------------------                   
|            Gilmour David           |
--------------------------------------
|            Sinatra Frank           |
--------------------------------------
|             David Bowie            |
--------------------------------------
|           Frusciante John          |
--------------------------------------
|     Wilhelm Friedrich Nietzsche    |
--------------------------------------
```

The problem is that names and surnames are not always in order.

How can i make a query like

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_1 WHERE NAME='JOHN FRUSCIANTE'
```

and findind 2 results?

Comment: Not entirely trivial, but it can be done. A few questions though. (1) What is your Oracle database version (for example, 11.2.0.3) - if you don't know, run `select banner from v$version` and see what it says. (2) Do you care about case (meaning John vs JOHN)? (3) How about John Doe vs. J Doe vs. J. Doe? (4) Hyphenated names? like Jean-Paul Sartre, is that the same as Jean Paul Sartre (and also, then, the same as Paul Sartre Jean)? (5) not critical, but to make things easier - is there also a primary key column in this table? Or are all the names distinct (guaranteed)?

Comment: (1) 10.2.0.1.0 that's the version
(2) sure, I have this huge table containing names written in all kind of ways
(3) Names could appear also like this
(4) This case it's not very common with italian's names but ir's better if my code is able to detect it.
(5) There is a column named 'NUM' that is the primary key

Comment: Alas, 10.2.0.1 is bad news. My solution uses `listagg()`, which is only available since Oracle 11.2 (which is itself almost out of *extended* support from Oracle). There are other ways to aggregate strings, but the solution will be even more complicated than what I posted (and you said what I posted is already too much...) - that will make it impossible to maintain.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way - ignoring most of the subtleties I mentioned in my comment to your question. The only one I addressed is a case-insensitive search.

The input, such as 'John Frusciante', is given as a bind variable, `:i_name`. The name can be one, two, three, or any other number of "tokens" - and they may be present in any order, including nonsensical orders like `Hussein Obama Barack` (where Obama is the family name, and Barack Hussein are the given names; first and middle names, in American terminology). For the test, I used 'John Frusciante' for the bind variable.

Regular expressions are convenient, but not fast. The query may be made faster in various ways (using standard string functions, but also in Oracle 12.1 or higher by using the `lateral` or `cross apply` clause, etc.) One problem will be `listagg()` if your Oracle Database version is 11.1 or lower since this function was only introduced in 11.2.

The strategy is straightforward - decompose each name into its tokens, then aggregate them back again in alphabetical order. I assume the table has an `id` column (if not, and if the data is in a stored table, I could use `rowid`, or else I can create an `id` on the fly, in an additional step).

```
with
  table_1 (id, name) as (
    select 1, 'John Frusciante'             from dual union all
    select 2, 'Gilmour David'               from dual union all  
    select 3, 'Sinatra Frank'               from dual union all
    select 4, 'David Bowie'                 from dual union all
    select 5, 'Frusciante John'             from dual union all
    select 6, 'Wilhelm Friedrich Nietzsche' from dual
  )
, prep (id, name, ordered_name) as (
    select  id, name, 
            listagg(regexp_substr(name,'\S+', 1, level), ' ') 
              within group
                (order by regexp_substr(name,'\S+', 1, level))
    from    table_1
    connect by  level <= regexp_count(name, '\S+')
            and prior id = id
            and prior sys_guid() is not null
    group   by id, name
  )
select name
from   prep
where  lower(ordered_name) = 
         (select  lower(listagg(regexp_substr(:i_name,'\S+', 1, level), ' ') 
                  within group 
                    (order by regexp_substr(:i_name,'\S+', 1, level)))
          from    dual
          connect by level <= regexp_count(:i_name, '\S+')
         )
;
```

Output (for input `'John Frusciante'`):

```
NAME
---------------
John Frusciante
Frusciante John
```

Comment: @ManneredPizza - The first part is just to simulate your data. Remove that - the query should begin with `with prep (id, ...)` - and use your actual table and column names in `prep`.

Answer (score 0):

Updated solution - please try the below:

```
with patterns as -- split each word in input search_string as a match-able pattern
(
    select regexp_substr(:search_string, '\w+', 1, level) pattern -- '\w+' matches one or more word characters
    from dual
    connect by regexp_substr(:search_string, '\w+', 1, level) is not null
) ,
table_1 as 
(
    select 'John Frusciante' as name from dual union all
    select 'John Frusciante John' as name from dual union all
    select 'Gilmour David' from dual union all 
    select 'Sinatra Frank' from dual union all 
    select 'David Bowie' from dual union all 
    select 'Frusciante John' from dual union all 
    select 'Wilhelm Friedrich Nietzsche' from dual union all  
    select 'John Smith'  from dual union all
    select 'Sarah Frusciante'  from dual
)
select name from (
select t.name,
       case sum( -- sum of all matches
                case instr(upper(t.name), upper(p.pattern)) -- match occurrence of each pattern in name
                    when 0 then 0   -- 0 when pattern is not found in name
                    else 1          -- 1 when each pattern is found in name
                end
                )
        when regexp_count(:search_string, '\w+', 1) -- count number of words in search string
        then 'matched'      -- match found for each word in search string
        else 'not matched'  -- not all words in search string is matched in the name
    end match_result
from table_1 t, patterns p
group by t.name
) where match_result = 'matched'
;
```

For `search_string` = `john frusciante` the output would be as follows:

```
NAME
---------------
John Frusciante
John John Frusciante
Frusciante John
```

My initial approach was to match multiple patterns in a string as follows:

```
select * from table_1 where regexp_like(name, '^(JOHN|FRUSCIANTE)', 'i');
```

However, this will also return a 'John Becket' and 'Sarah Frusciante' as rightly pointed out by @mathguy

Comment: I don't think this is what the OP wanted. Your query will also return John Becket and Sarah Frusciante. Moreover, he is probably looking for a generic solution where the "searched" name is an input (perhaps a bind variable), so its component names can't be hard-coded in the query.

Comment: @mathguy : That's true, thanks for reviewing and pointing that out. I've edited to include a slightly different approach based on your suggestion. Your solution works perfectly too and great questions on the original post comments! Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below for your purpose

1) This is based on the given search string that should have first name and surname in any order.

2)Also, the first name and surname should not be the same.

```
        WITH table_1 (id, name)
             AS (SELECT 1,
                        'John george Frusciante'
                 FROM   dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 2,
                        'Gilmour David'
                 FROM   dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 3,
                        'Sinatra Frank'
                 FROM   dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 4,
                        'JOHN Frusciante'
                 FROM   dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 5,
                        'Friedrich Nietzsche Wilhelm'
                 FROM   dual
                 UNION ALL
                 SELECT 6,
                        'Wilhelm Friedrich Nietzsche'
                 FROM   dual),
                 input1 as(select replace('Wilhelm Friedrich Nietzsche',' ','|') string1 from dual)
        SELECT a.*
        FROM   table_1 a,input1
        WHERE regexp_like(name, '^'||string1, 'i')
        AND regexp_like(name, string1||'$', 'i')
        AND upper(REGEXP_substr(name,'^(\S*)'))<>upper(REGEXP_substr(name,'(\S*)$'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Something as simple as this may work well for you:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_1
WHERE NAME LIKE '%JOHN%'
AND NAME LIKE '%FRUSCIANTE%'
```

Comment: The problem is that the name that i'm searching for is an input variable and I don't know if it's made by 2 or more "parts"